# Show a custom 404 blade for BadMethodCallException in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel

I am using dynamic controller actions for Laravel web routing. As an example,

**if the controller is and a function inside it are :-**

```
//namespaces and other traits and classes

class CountryController extends Controller{
   public function showAllCountry(){
     return view('all-countries');
   }
}
```

The url would be `localhost/<projectfolder-name>/Country/showAllCountry`

If the function or the controller does not exist, example if I type the URL as `localhost/<projectfolder-name>/CountryCode/showAllCountry` or `localhost/<projectfolder-name>/Country/showMyCountry`, etc. , it throws a `BadMethodCallException` as follows

```
BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\Country::showMyCountrydoes not exist.
```

or

```
BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\CountryCode::showAllCountry not exist.
```

What I want is, instead of doing that, **it should show a custom 404 blade that I designed**. How do I do it.

For reference, I am writing the Dynamic controller action from `web.php` here

**web.php**

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{controller}/{action?}/{params1?}/{params2?}', function ($controller, $action = 'index', $params1 = '',$params2 = '') {

    $params = explode('/', $params1);
    $params[1] = $params2;
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make("\App\Http\Controllers\\" . ucwords($controller) . 'Controller');
    return $controller->callAction($action, $params);
})->middleware('supadminauth');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's `method_exists()` function to check if a function exists in class.

For example: In your route closure

```
if(! method_exists($controller, $action)) {
    return 404;
}
return $controller->callAction($action, $params);
```

Comment: But, if the user changes the name of the Controller as - `localhost/<projectfolder-name>/CountryCode/showAllCountry` and the Controller does not exist, then it shows `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [\App\Http\Controllers\Dashboar2dController] does not exist.`. Is there any way to show 404 error for this as well?

Comment: I'll point you in the right direction with [this url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) but let you figure it out yourself.

Comment: Happy to help :)